# Spearman correlation not identical with Pearson correlation using ranks in R

Tags: r, correlation

When looking at the R help it says:

> Note that "spearman" basically computes cor(R(x), R(y)) (or cov(., .)) where R(u) := rank(u, na.last = "keep")

However when I tried to calculate a correlation, once with method="spearman" and once with method="pearson" but using the ranks, I got different results when my data contained missings.

```
set.seed(23525)
a<-rnorm(100,50,1)
b<-a+rnorm(100,0,2)
a[1]<-NA
b[2]<-NA

cor(a,b,use="complete.obs",method="spearman") # 0.3292785
cor(rank(a,na.last="keep"),rank(b,na.last="keep"),use="complete.obs") # 0.3255958
```

Using "complete.obs" should do a casewise deletion of my data. But apparently it does not. If I do a casewise deletion manually I get my expected result:

```
cor(rank(a[-c(1,2)],na.last="keep"),rank(b[-c(1,2)],na.last="keep"),use="complete.obs") 
# 0.3292785
```

So I am confused why both methods do not yield the same result. Can someone explain this? Is there something I am overlooking?

Comment: The difference would be that `rank(a, na.last="keep")` is not the same as same as `rank(a[-c(1, 2)])`.  In the first, you are ranking `n-1` terms and then dropping two after the ranking (the missing and one ranked), and in the second you are dropping two terms and ranking the remainder.

Comment: Thank you very much. So when I use the spearman correlation it is doing the casewise deletion first and then ranks the remaining values... which makes sense now when I think about it.